# Is there a non-minified dev environment for Instagram's embed.js?

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

When using Instagram's [embeds.js](http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js) which is minimally documented on their [website](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/), I get the error:

> Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for
>   the full error message and additional helpful warnings.

I cannot find a way to use the "non-minified dev environment". Is there a way to do this? Without being able to do this, is there some other way to figure out what the error could be?